# sbt (Scala) via SSH results in command not found, but works if I do it myself

Tags: bash, scala, ssh, sbt

So I'm trying to do something that involves running `sbt` over an SSH command, and this is what I'm trying:

```
ssh my_username@<server ip> "cd <project folder>; sbt 'run-main Foo' "
```

When I do that however, I get an error message: `bash: sbt: command not found`

Then I go SSH into the server myself, `cd` to the project folder, and run `sbt 'run-main Foo'` and everything works nicely. I have checked to make sure `sbt` is on the `$PATH` variable on the remote server via `ssh my_username@<server ip> "echo $PATH"` and it shows the correct value.

I feel like this is a simple fix, but cannot figure it out... help?
Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you log in, `bash` is run as an interactive shell. When you run commands directly through `ssh`, bash is run as a non-interactive shell, and therefore different initialization files are sourced (see the bash manual pages for which exactly). There are a number of ways to fix this, e.g.:

- Use the full path to `sbt` when calling it directly through `ssh`
- Edit `.bashrc` and add the missing directories to the `PATH` environment variable

Note that your test `ssh my_username@<server ip> "echo $PATH"` actually prints `PATH` on your client, not your server, because of the double quotes. Use `ssh my_username@<server ip> 'echo $PATH'` or `ssh my_username@<server ip> env` to print `PATH` from the server's environment. When checking using `env`, you will see that `PS1` is only set in interactive shells.