# SSH command from within a Scala program with pure Scala API or Ammonite API

Tags: scala, ammonite

I would like to perform an SSH command and then execute some command on a distant machine from within scala. Both the scala API and Scala Ammonite provide way to execute system command. However I am having problem with ssh. How do i run an ssh command and then run command and get the result back in from within my scala program ?

## EDIT1

found the following in that post [Problems using scala to remotely issue commands via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942386/problems-using-scala-to-remotely-issue-commands-via-ssh)

"ssh user@Main.local 'mkdir Desktop/test'".!

I wonder how can this be done with scala Amonite API. I have not been able to find the way.

Comment: without knowing what you are trying to do it is hard to answer but maybe you can run a bash script prior to the scala jar/script that will run ssh commands for you and save the result somewhere the scala code can access it?

Comment: Nononono I want to do all of it within Scala. So far using te second approach I get my result as a string. I would like to have the output stream instead. STD out. To make is simple i am trying to run ls. This works: "ssh ... ls"!! But the  return in a string. I want a steam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far found what i wanted with the Scala API: 
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html
e.g.

> ```
>  import scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder  
>  import scala.sys.process._ 
>  import scala.sys.process
>
>  "ssh 192.168.0.103  ls IdeaProjects" lineStream
> ```

It works as a charm Executed from one of my machine to the other it worked flawlessly. This require a phraseless ssh to be set up in advance. I am the same use on both machine to other i would have had to specify the user as well

If someone can complement the Answer and explain how to do it with the Ammonite API that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cable](https://github.com/zhongwm/cable) to do your SSH tasks,
Cable supports ~/.ssh config as well as global ssh client config.
Cable also supports jumping over networks, jumping over bastion hosts.
Cable allows tasks composing within a host and across many different hosts.